# Recorded video perfect on android but out of sync on desktop

Tags: android, video, synchronization, record, mediarecorder

I am trying to record from the video camera in my application. I have removed try/catch blocks and things of that nature to show an example of how to record:

```
camera.unlock();
mediaRecorder.setCamera(camera);
mediaRecorder.reset();
mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);

CamcorderProfile mCamcorderProfile = CamcorderProfile.get(CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT, CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_720P);
mediaRecorder.setProfile(mCamcorderProfile);

/*      
mediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(8000000);
mediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(5000000);
mediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(3000000);
*/

mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mSurfaceHolder.getSurface());
mRecFile = File.createTempFile("Video", ".mp4", mRecVideoPath);
mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(mRecFile.getAbsolutePath());
mediaRecorder.prepare();
mediaRecorder.start();
```

I record the video and it plays perfectly on the phone. Then I pull the video file off and I play it on a PC and the audio/video is slightly out of sync on a short 10 second clip. This only happens when recorded with a Samsung Note 3.

Just to be thorough, here is what I have tried:

- Works perfectly on a Nexus 7
- Works perfectly on a Samsung S3
- Tried recording on two different Note 3
- Tried various bitrates

For playing the out of sync video from the Note 3:

- Played video on a Macbook pro, Chrome browser
- Played video on a Macbook pro, quicktime
- Played video on a Win7 pc

Out of sync on all of them.

When recording a video on the Note 3 with the stock camera app there is NO sync issue!

Update that I forgot: Using the highest quality setting I recorded a video with my app and one video with the stock camera. I inspected both videos and this is the output. I forget now which was which but the output is identical as far as I can tell.

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '20140719_155219.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isom3gp4
    creation_time   : 2014-07-19 20:52:24
  Duration: 00:00:04.97, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 16674 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080, 17093 kb/s, 29.92 fps, 29.92 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-07-19 20:52:24
      handler_name    : VideoHandle
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 117 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-07-19 20:52:24
      handler_name    : SoundHandle

Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '20140719160307.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isom3gp4
    creation_time   : 2014-07-19 21:03:07
  Duration: 00:00:06.61, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 16530 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080, 16473 kb/s, 29.92 fps, 29.92 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-07-19 21:03:07
      handler_name    : VideoHandle
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 117 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-07-19 21:03:07
      handler_name    : SoundHandle
```

Comment: Have you tried recording with different audio encoders? What I'd do is inspect the output file from the stock app and see what audio codec they used and compare it to your file. You could also check if 3GP container gives a better result than MP4.

Comment: Thanks a lot for reminding me that I had some ffmpeg outputs that I forgot to attach, I will try some different audio codecs and see what happens. My main concern/question would be if the file will play across ALL pcs, browsers and macs if I start changing from the mp4 codec? Right now it is using pretty standard stuff.

Comment: The combination H.264/ACC/MP4 is a good default that's well supported.  Just out of curiosity you could check if setting the audio codec to AMR_NB causes the same sync issue, if not, the AAC encoder on the Note 3 may be buggy, and the built in decoder may compensate for the bug while the desktop decoders don't. Still, that  doesn't explain why the stock app's output is in sync. The only other thought I have is that the method call order is not exactly like the Camera guide (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#capture-video) and there's a reset call after setCamera.

Comment: App just crashes with AMR_NB or AMR_WB, says not supported. I downloaded multiple "example" projects that all display the same problem. The only ones that don't are projects that use the built in camera application (using an Intent) instead of a custom camera.

Comment: please copy-paste the output with more details: **ffprobe -print_format json -show_streams**. Through the test we do for our recording app out-of-sync issue happens if audio stream is longer than video's one.

Comment: It seems like HTML5 player can adjust and fix out-of-sync on the fly, but flash or Android players can't do the same.